# Anonymous users can't access to image style field

Tags: 8, users, media, files

### Entity

- Type : block
- Field : 'Reference to entity : image style' *(field_image_style)*
- Manage display : I display the Entity ID

[image]

### Twig

In my twig template, I get the *field_image_style* data from `content.field_image_style`.

### Issue

**Works great on admin user, but not when browsing the website as an anonymous user.**

This is not a image style generation error, or a wrong permission to files folders : you can access to both original image and generated styled image on anonymous.

And this is where it gets weird. It's working when you give the "Administer image styles" permission to anonymous users.

[image]

### Dump

Just to show you what result I have, here's a dump of `content.field_image_style` with an admin user :

[image]

And with an anonymous user :

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear about what you are trying to do. This part *"This is not a image style generation error, or a wrong permission to files folders : you can access to both original image and generated styled image on anonymous."* suggests you want to display a styled image, the rest of the question is about how to display the id of an image style config entity.

Comment: I know how to display an image with a specific image style. In my twig template, I want to get the image style id if it exists, and display my image with this image style. The problem is I have access to image style field only on admin user.

Comment: But how does the rendered output of the config entity id helps to display an image?

Comment: Like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9G55.png (I use the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) for the `image_style` twig filter

Comment: @4k4 It is a reference to an entity, so it's like it can't display an entity (the image style in this example) if it does not have the permission to see this entity. It might work well for taxonomy terms or nodes, but I can't give access to image style administration for anonymous users "just" for that. Maybe i'm wrong or I'm missing something, but this is how I see it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a field configured in a view mode is to render the output.

To process field values in code use the entity object. You'll find this in a block template in this variable:

```
$variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']
```

So in TWIG you can try to access the field value like this:

```
{%
  set style = elements.content['#block_content'].field_image_style.target_id
%}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you ! I just don't get why you can't use the `content` variable like in any other field. Maybe I'm wrong but I usually look at the [available variables](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21templates%21block.html.twig/8.2.x) for a template, and I don't see a reference of `elements`.

Comment: It's hard to explain this in one comment. `content` is the main content of the block. As always in Drupal this means this is a render array. Now coding with a render array is no fun, because it is a moving target. It changes a lot, not only because of access rights, because it only is required to be renderable. Even the position of the fields is not fixed (install a layout module). So if you want to write code it's better to use an API which doesn't change and for this entites are perfect.

Comment: Now the problem here is, `block_content` has not a template of its own, which probably would have a documented entity, like `node` in a node template. The generic block template covers all blocks, not only the ones for custom blocks and so there is no specific variable for this entity.